# Google API: Access token is not refreshing

Tags: python, reactjs, google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement the following logic:

1. User opens my website page and clicks a button
2. The popup shows to ask for a consent to upload files to his Google drive
3. Users agrees, I grabs the auth_code, obtain access and refresh tokens
4. When necessarily, later, I upload some documents to his Google drive not asking permissions anymore.

The first 3 points finally work. The code on the client side (ReactJS):

```
componentWillMount() {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('id', 'google_script');
    const self = this;
    script.onload = function() {
        gapi.load('auth2', ()=>{
            const clientId = window.googleClientId;
            const scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file';
            let config = {
                clientId: clientId,
                scope: scope
            };
            self.googleAuth = gapi.auth2.init(config);
        });
    };
    script.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
};
```

// Then

```
buttonClick(){
    this.googleAuth.grantOfflineAccess().then((data)=>{ //<== Offline access
        if (data.code){
            this.saveGoogleDriveToken(data.code); //<-- Sends to the server
        } else {

        }
    });
}
```

Server side, exchanging code to tokens.

```
def get_tokens(auth_code):
    json_path = os.path.join(static_folder_path, "client_secrets.json")
    credentials = None
    try:
        credentials = client.credentials_from_clientsecrets_and_code(
            json_path,
            scopes,
            auth_code)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        return None
    return {
        'access_token': credentials.access_token,
        'refresh_token': credentials.refresh_token
    }
```

I save these 2 tokens in the database. Later, when I want to upload documents:

```
    credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(user_access_token,
                                                        refresh_token = user_refresh_token,
                                                        token_uri = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
                                                        client_id = get_config_var('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
                                                        client_secret = get_config_var('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET')
    )

drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
fd = io.BytesIO(invoice_file_bytes)
body = {'name': invoice_file_name, 'mimeType': 'application/pdf'}
media_body = MediaIoBaseUpload(fd = fd, mimetype='application/pdf')
file = drive_service.files().create(body=body,
                                            media_body=media_body,
                                            fields='id').execute() #<== When hit here
```

But I can't make it work. It worked soon after a user gave the consent but not after 1 hour (when the access token is expired I think) What I have is **'invalid_client: Unauthorized', '{\n  "error": "invalid_client",\n  "error_description": "Unauthorized"\n}**')

I read google api can refresh the access token on its own but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The google API library you're using doesn't let you refresh the access token from client side code for security reasons. You would have to refresh the token from your server side python code if it is expired in get_tokens.

```
    credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(user_access_token,
                                                        refresh_token = user_refresh_token,
                                                        token_uri = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
                                                        client_id = get_config_var('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
                                                        client_secret = get_config_var('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET')
    )
http = cred.authorize(httplib2.Http())
credentials.refresh(http)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
fd = io.BytesIO(invoice_file_bytes)
body = {'name': invoice_file_name, 'mimeType': 'application/pdf'}
media_body = MediaIoBaseUpload(fd = fd, mimetype='application/pdf')
file = drive_service.files().create(body=body,
                                            media_body=media_body,
                                            fields='id').execute() #<== When hit here
```

Comment: I don't understand why is that. From here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline  "If you use a Google API Client Library, the client object refreshes the access token as needed as long as you configure that object for offline access." I assumed I use the same approach and it should refresh itself, am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks but you code is not working. 'Credentials' object has no attribute 'authorize'

Comment: You said "The google API library you're using doesn't let you refresh the access token from client side code" - but I'm trying to refresh the access token from the server side.